# C++ Error when Initializing a pointer to a pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, heap-memory

I am using a large code-base, so forgive me for not including all source code. I will summarize the problem as best I can and hopefully it is enough to give some intuition into an answer.

When creating a pointer to a pointer (used as a dynamic array of pointers), I get an error somewhere in the heap, see image below for call-stack:

[image: Error]

all setFrontNodes() is:

```
void Node::setFrontNodes(int size) {
    frontNodes = new Node*[size]; // ERROR ON THIS LINE
    nFrontNodes = size;
}
```

Where the header for my class Node is:

```
class Node {
public:
    ~Node();
    int nBackNodes;
    int nFrontNodes;
    Node** backNodes;
    Node** frontNodes;
    void setFrontNodes(int size);
    void setBackNodes(int size);
    double value;
    double valuePrime;
    ActivationFunction* activationFunction = NULL;
    InitWeightMethod* initWeightMethod = NULL;
    void initWeights(double multiplier);
    double bias;
    double deltaBias;
    double* weights;
    double* deltaWeights;
    double errorGradient;
    Node(int number);
    void forwardProp();
    int number;
    string label;
    int layer;
};
```

Now here is the strange issue. The error will happen randomly. I will run the same program with same parameters and everything, and the error will either happen there, or at another time while running, or not at all! This makes it extremely difficult to track the bug down and why I do not have a full code example that can be repeated.

It sounds like there is some issue allocating memory on the heap, though I am not sure what it could be or how to fix it. Vectors do not cause errors but are mind numbingly slow when training neural networks such as I am using the code for.

I ran memory diagnostics, and I still have over 4gb free of RAM when the error happens.

Thanks for any time! Let me know if you want anything else, but like I said it is a large program and the error appears random so I am looking for a general problem that I might be running into when allocating memory on the heap which is causing the ntdll.dll!_RtlReportCriticalFailure@12() error in the screenshot.

Comment: I see two possibilities. Either `size` is a garbage, very large value (possibly uninitialized variable); or your program is corrupting the heap elsewhere, in the code not shown.

Comment: I updated with a new screen shot, size is only 200, so that is not the problem. So i must be corrupting the heap elsewhere, do you have any references or advice on this? I am a self-taught programmer, so ignorant to some things.

Comment: once you fix your code, it may run just as slowly as the vector implementation.  consider investing time understanding the vector performance issue instead trying to maintain this fragile structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by Igor Tandetnik, this sort of error is likely due either to a garbage value for `size`, or due to the heap being corrupted. Make sure `size` is a valid number, and make sure that you're not writing to memory you're not supposed to touch (as this could corrupt the heap).

If possible, you can use a code sanitizer (like clang) to check for this, or you could use a tool like valgrind to see when it happens.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will check out clang and valgrind. I updated the question with a new screenshot that is more informative, does this help at all? It does shows that size=200 so that is not the issue, but what about the block address?

Comment: In this case, the place where the error occurs is not the place where the code is broken. The code breaks prior to that point, most likely due to heap corruption, and it would require going through a lot more code to understand where the heap corruption occurs.

Comment: Tools like valgrind and address sanitizers can check for things like heap corruption, and pinpoint where it occurs.

Comment: Your program has data structures that keep track of allocated memory. This is the heap. When those data structures get overwritten (usually because of a bad write or a bug in the code), that’s what causes heap corruption.

Comment: hmm I working on tracing down the bug, thanks now I know (kind-of) what to look for! I'd like to find it myself rather than using a program because I might learning something.

Comment: Good luck! Glad I could help!

Comment: I found it! I had an index out of bounds on another pointer to a pointer. Weird that the error was not thrown at the out of bounds line?

Comment: Glad you found it!

Comment: Ya thanks for the help! Do you know why the error wasn't caught before this?

Comment: Writing to out of bounds memory is like playing Russian roulette. You might not actually break something important - whether or not something important gets broken depends on the memory layout of the program, which changes between runs because memory allocations take memory from the operating system (meaning that it depends on other programs on the system).

Comment: Ohhh so that is why it was random! If the out-of-bounds bumps into some allocated memory at that out-of-bounds location.. boom corrupted. Thanks a ton, I did learn something xD

Comment: Yea. You do gotta be careful. Btw what did you mean when you said `vector` was slow for you?

Comment: when accessing elements from the vector, training the neural net is a long iterative process so it definitely adds up.

Comment: Did you enable optimizations when training? They usually make all the overhead of accessing elements in a vector go away